# AKKA Remote Actor Error

Tags: scala, akka-remote-actor

I am trying to run an AKKA remote example by

```
1. Running the remote actor in a machine with IP 192.168.1.7
2. Running the local from my machine
```

The remote actor is started up in the machine (with ip address 192.168.1.7); but when I start Local actor from my machine, its not able to connect to the remote actor. Please find the Local and Remote actor system configuration:

Local:

```
akka {
  //loglevel = "INFO"
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0
    }
    //log-sent-messages = on
    //log-received-messages = on
  }
}
```

Remote:

```
akka {
  //loglevel = "INFO"
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 5150
    }
    //log-sent-messages = on
    //log-received-messages = on
  }
}
```

Code in the local system to connect to remote actor:

```
class LocalActor extends Actor {
  val remote = context.actorFor("akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@192.168.1.7:5150/user/RemoteActor")
  var counter = 0
  def receive = {
    case "START" => 
        remote ! "Hello from the LocalActor"
    case msg: String => 
        println(s"LocalActor received message: '$msg'")
        if (counter < 5) {
            sender ! "Hello back to you"
            counter += 1
        }
  }
}
```

When I start the local system, I get the below Message:

```
C:\Users\AnandKrishnan\Documents\GitHub\AkkaRemoteActorsHelloWorld\HelloLocal [master +0 ~5 -0]> sbt run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Set current project to HelloLocal (in build file:/C:/Users/AnandKrishnan/Documents/GitHub/AkkaRemoteActorsHelloWorld/HelloLocal/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\AnandKrishnan\Documents\GitHub\AkkaRemoteActorsHelloWorld\HelloLocal\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[warn] there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Running local.Local
[INFO] [02/14/2016 22:57:11.755] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [02/14/2016 22:57:12.163] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.0.1:50830]
[INFO] [02/14/2016 22:57:12.163] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.0.1:50830]
[WARN] [02/14/2016 22:57:13.351] [LocalSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] [akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.0.1:50830/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp
%3A%2F%2FHelloRemoteSystem%40192.168.1.7%3A5150-0/endpointWriter] AssociationError [akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.0.1:50830] -> [akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@192.168.1.7:5150]: Error
 [Invalid address: akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@192.168.1.7:5150] [
akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@192.168.1.7:5150
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.Transport$InvalidAssociationException: Connection refused: no further information: /192.168.1.7:5150
]
[WARN] [02/14/2016 22:57:13.371] [LocalSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6] [Remoting] Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@192.168.1.7:5150]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: no further information: /192.168.1.7:5150
[INFO] [02/14/2016 22:57:13.389] [LocalSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://LocalSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://LocalSystem/user/LocalActor#1441959988] to Actor[akka://LocalSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the Remote Actor class you have:

```
val system = ActorSystem("HelloRemoteSystem", config)
```

Make sure that in the Local actor when using `actorSelection`/`actorFor` you use the same name like:

```
val remoteActor = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2553/user/RemoteActor")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for an Akka actor system to communicate with other hosts, the actor system must bind to a hostname or IP that is routable by the other host in question.  `localhost`, of course, is not.

Your remote system needs to bind to 192.168.1.7:

```
akka {
  remote {
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "192.168.1.7"
    }
  }
}
```

Of course in production you'll likely want to use hostnames rather than IPs.

Comment: Hi my remote actor is running on 192.168.1.7. Also in the code for local while creating the actor  (val remote) I am meeting the remote IP. Can you be bit more specific in which part in the configuration above I need to make change? Local conf or remote?

Comment: I had a similar problem with this same example. Apparently the hostname does not get treated the same as the actual IP. Why is this? And what can be done about it? Because you're right, I'd much rather use hostnames.

Comment: If I set remote hostname to the IP of the machine then I get an exception saying `Failed to bind ...`  `cannot assign requested address`.